# jQuery Get Input Name Array Key Value from Neighbouring TD

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hard one to explain in the title, but a bit of code says it all:

```
<tr class="">
  <td>
    <input value="9" name="set[122][order]"></input>
    <input class="set-id" type="hidden" value="1" name="set[122][ex_id]"></input>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input value="0.00" name="set[122][weight]"></input>
  </td>
  <td> … </td>
  <td>
    <img class="deleteRowButton" border="0" title="Toggle Delete Set" alt="Delete Set" src="mysite/images/icons/png/delete-3x.png"></img>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have a bit of jQuery code that is activated when the img (deleteRowButton) is clicked:

```
$('.deleteRowButton').click (function() {

  $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass( "deleteSet" );
  var id = $('.set-id', $(this).closest('td')).val(); // this bit not working

  $('.editWoForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="deleteSet[]" value="' + id + '" />');
});
```

The deleteRowButton code basically just inserts a hidden input tag at the bottom of my form, so i have the ability to process these to remove entries from db.

BUT, what I need to do is grab the value from `set[]`, so in this example `122`. It can come from any of the inputs, as the whole `tr` is related to one entry. `122` is the db id, so that's what I need to grab.

So ideally, when the user clicks on the deleteRowButton, it generates and inserts:

```
<input type="hidden" name="deleteSet[]" value="122" />
```

Thanks in advance!

---

### Solution

Thanks to @ArunPJohny for the assistance.

```
$('.deleteRowButton').click (function() {
  var $tr = $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass( "deleteSet" );
  var id = $tr.find('.set-id').attr('name').match(/\d+/)[0];

  if($tr.hasClass( "deleteSet" )){
    $('.editWoForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="deleteSet[]" value="' + id + '" />');
  }
  else{
    $('input[name="deleteSet[]"][value="' + id + '"]').remove();
  }
});
```

This will get the id, append a hidden input field with said id as the value, then if the button is pressed again (to toggle the delete state) the hidden input field is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way here is to fine the `set-id` element which is within the current `tr` element. what you are trying to do is to find an `set-id` which is within the `td` which contains the clicked `deleteRowButton`.

```js
$('.deleteRowButton').click(function() {

  //use closest instead of parents
  var $tr = $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("deleteSet");
  //find the set-id within the current tr
  var id = $tr.find('.set-id').attr('name').match(/\d+/)[0];
  //$('.editWoForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="deleteSet[]" value="' + id + '" />');
  $('#log').text(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="">
    <td>
      <input value="9" name="set[122][order]"/>
      <input class="set-id" type="hidden" value="1" name="set[122][ex_id]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="0.00" name="set[122][weight]"/>
    </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
      <img class="deleteRowButton" border="0" title="Toggle Delete Set" alt="Delete Set" src="mysite/images/icons/png/delete-3x.png"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>
      <input value="9" name="set[123][order]"/>
      <input class="set-id" type="hidden" value="2" name="set[123][ex_id]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="0.00" name="set[123][weight]"/>
    </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
      <img class="deleteRowButton" border="0" title="Toggle Delete Set" alt="Delete Set" src="mysite/images/icons/png/delete-3x.png"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this grab the `value` attribute? Which in this case = `1`. This is not what I am trying to get, I am trying to get at the `122` inside `name="set[122][xxx]`

Comment: Aha, this is good. I am sticking with my original tactic of adding a hidden input though, as I just want to build an array (deleteSet[]) of items to be deleted. So now I can do this thank you! BUT if I change my mind and press the delete button again, the toggleClass removes the class `deleteSet` but it adds another hidden input, as I have clicked the button again. I need to somehow toggle the hidden inputs to match the class of the TR. Thanks again!